# Why does this code throws exception

Tags: java, classcastexception

```
    HashMap h = new HashMap();
    Collection c = h.values();
    Object[] a = c.toArray();
    LinkedList<Object[]> l = new LinkedList<Object[]>();
    l.addFirst(a);
    TreeSet<Object[]> t = new TreeSet<Object[]>(l); //throws ClassCastException exception
```

Since I'm not violating any contracts, this exception is weird.

Comment: The only thing that is weird here is why you haven't looked up that constructor to see why it throws that exception.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The TreeSet constructor throws a [*ClassCastException*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ClassCastException.html) if a collection is passed whose elements do not all implement [Comparable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html). *Object[]* does not implement [Comparable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html).

Refer to the [constructor reference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html#TreeSet(java.util.Collection)) for more details.

> [ClassCastException](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ClassCastException.html) - if the elements in c are not [Comparable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html), or are not mutually comparable
>   [NullPointerException](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/NullPointerException.html) - if the specified collection is null